# Swagger: Unable to find model that actually exists

Tags: java, spring, swagger, openapi, springfox

I'm using Spring Boot v2.6.0 to create a simple hosting service.
For Swagger I'm using SpringFox version 3.0.0, and Swagger2.

As I've never used Swagger or OpenAPI inside my Spring projects I'm out of ideas.
I'm having an issue with this method:

```java
    @CrossOrigin
    @Operation(summary = "Check if a resourcepack exists with the specified id.")
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "200", description = "Resourcepack found", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ExistsResponse.class))
    })
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "400", description = "Bad Request", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class))
    })
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "403", description = "Blacklisted IP", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class))
    })
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "429", description = "Too Many Requests (rate-limited)", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = RateLimitResponse.class))
    })
    @ApiResponse(responseCode = "500", description = "Internal Error (unseen exceptions)", content = {
            @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class))
    })
    @GetMapping(value = "/api/exists/{id:.+}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ExistsResponse> exists(@Parameter(description = "Id of the resourcepack to be checked") @PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request) throws InternalErrorException {
```

I get the following error when navigating to swagger-ui, for all models except the ExistsResponse one.

```
2022-08-05 17:29:18.057 ERROR 17372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] nceModelSpecificationToPropertyConverter : Unable to find a model that matches key ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='net.iceyleagons.resourcehost.responses', name='ErrorResponse'}, viewDiscriminator=null, validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}
2022-08-05 17:29:18.058 ERROR 17372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] nceModelSpecificationToPropertyConverter : Unable to find a model that matches key ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='net.iceyleagons.resourcehost.responses', name='ErrorResponse'}, viewDiscriminator=null, validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}
2022-08-05 17:29:18.058 ERROR 17372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] nceModelSpecificationToPropertyConverter : Unable to find a model that matches key ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='net.iceyleagons.resourcehost.responses', name='RateLimitResponse'}, viewDiscriminator=null, validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}
2022-08-05 17:29:18.059 ERROR 17372 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] nceModelSpecificationToPropertyConverter : Unable to find a model that matches key ModelKey{qualifiedModelName=ModelName{namespace='net.iceyleagons.resourcehost.responses', name='ErrorResponse'}, viewDiscriminator=null, validationGroupDiscriminators=[], isResponse=true}
```

I'm using Lombok on my models. As an example here is my RateLimitResponse class:

```java
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RateLimitResponse {

    private final long refill;
    private final String error;

    public static RateLimitResponse from(RateLimitedException e) {
        return new RateLimitResponse(e.getRefill(), e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

As a comparison here's the ExistsResponse:

```java
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ExistsResponse {

    private final String downloadUrl;
    private final boolean exists;
    private final long available;
    private final long remainingTokens;

    public static ExistsResponse found(String downloadUrl, long available, long remainingTokens) {
        return new ExistsResponse(downloadUrl, true, available, remainingTokens);
    }

    public static ExistsResponse empty(long remainingTokens) {
        return new ExistsResponse("", false, -1, remainingTokens);
    }
}
```

I have no idea why this does not affect the ExistsResponse model, as it's constructed in a totally equal way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was searching through the internet I found, that SpringFox's current version doesn't really support `@ControllerAdvice` (or rather Exceptions) and there's an open issue related to this on GitHub. (https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/521)

I was able to fix my problem by using springdoc instead of Springfox.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things wrong here with your code here.

1. multiple @ApiResponse objects not wrapped

According to the swagger documentation for [`@ApiResponses`](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.X/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiResponses.html), the `@ApiResponse` object must be wrapped in the responses wrapper.  The [`@ApiResponse` documentation](https://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiResponse.html) says "This annotation is not used directly and will not be parsed by Swagger. It should be used within the ApiResponses."

2. Controller Advice

You should have an `@ControllerAdvice` class to manage all exceptions.  There's a great article on how to do this [here](https://medium.com/@jovannypcg/understanding-springs-controlleradvice-cd96a364033f), but feel free to find your own.

3. Method Signature

Your method signature is `ResponseEntity<ExistsResponse>`.  It can't return another response (unless you define it in `@ControllerAdvice`).  Make this generic if possible, like `ResponseEntity<?>`.

A couple of other notes:

1. @Data already includes the `@RequiredArgsConstructor`, so there's no need to add that annotation here.
2. The `@RequiredArgsConstructor` makes a contructor consisting of fields marked with `@NonNull`.  In your case, since you don't have fields annotated this way, then your `@RequiredArgsConstructor` is basically acting the same as a `@NoArgsConstructor`.
3. Java automatically creates a `NoArgsConstructor` at compile time for a class with no constructors.  There's no need to declare the `@RerquiredArgsConstructor` unless you are also declaring an `@AllArgsConstructor` and/or an `@NoArgsConstructor`.
4. `@Data` does a lot of stuff.  If you are only using it as a simple object, maybe consider `@Value` instead.

Comment: I do have a ControllerAdvice class.
Changes I've made:
Converted response classes to records.
Wrapped ApiResponse in ApiResponses.
 - made method only return ExistsResponse, because the ControllerAdvice handles the rest

Unfortunately, the same unable to find model error still applies, but not for the exists response one.
Until your follow-up, I'll try experimenting more, and if I find a solution I'll answer it here.